# Floating DIV down with CSS but breaks up existing lines of content

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout

I have a DIV that contains a sign up form that is automatically floated approximately 400px down from the top of the page. (I'm trying to keep it above the fold.) This normally works very well, but occasionally the DIV splits a line of text awkwardly as in the image below.  How can I prevent lines of text from being broken in the middle of the line?

**Example of text breaking up**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"><form id="myform"></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    -moz-transform: translate( 0, 100px) scale(.8);
    -webkit-transform: translate( 0, 100px) scale(.8);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 100px) scale(.8);
    transform:translate( 0, 100px) scale(.8);
}
#container form {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    
#container:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
```

**Edit:**  I've tried wrapping the container div with another div and making that `width: 100% !important` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Any chance we could get a [mcve] in a snippet?

Comment: @showdev, it needs to allow text to flow above and below, just not the sides.

Comment: @AlexanderNied, I thought about a working example, but the code is auto generated by WordPress plugin.  I'm not sure I could code it manually to create the same problem.  It's also completely dependent on the user's screen resolution.

Comment: @Trebor What if you set `#container form` `width` to `100%`?

Comment: @HuyPhạm, I played with that, but it still has the same problem of breaking up the surrounding text.